# A few questions about photos not showing up in my gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to make a gallery using ajax, but my code runs into some errors (this is for homework). The error is showing up on developer console around my two splits. Also my webpage opens but no photos show up, how can i properly call the pictures from my text file? I'm new to javascripting.
Thank you.

```html
<head>
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style src="text/css">
.navBtn {
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color: red;
font-weight: 1000;
color: white;
}

div {
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 10px;
width: 70%;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="imgContainer">
<img id="image" />
</div>
<div>
<button class="navBtn" onclick="previous()">
<< Previous</button>
<button class="navBtn" onclick="next

()">Next >></button>
<br>
<button onclick="pageLoad.init

()">Update Image </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var totalImage;
var currentIndex;

var pageLoad = {
imgData: "5",
pagePrefix: "Null",
slides: "5",

init: function () {
$.ajax({
url: "./images.txt",
async: false,
success: function (data) {
pageLoad.imgData = data.split

('\n');
totalImage =

pageLoad.imgData.length;
currentIndex = 0;
changeImg();
}
});
}
};
pageLoad.init();

function changeImg() {
document.getElementById

("image").setAttribute("src", "./img/" +

pageLoad.imgData[currentIndex].split(' ')[0]);
setTimeout(function () {
next();
}, pageLoad.imgData[currentIndex].split('

')[1]);
}

function previous() {
if (currentIndex == 0) {
currentIndex = totalImage - 1;
} else {
currentIndex--;
}
changeImg();
};

function next() {
if (currentIndex == totalImage - 1) {
currentIndex = 0;
} else {
currentIndex++;
}
changeImg();
};

setTimeout(function () {
next();
}, 3000);

</script>
</body
```

The webpage opens showing 5 photos that you can go through

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't run either - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, could you edit it so that it runs, so we can see what sorts of problems come up?